# Inheritance method "virtual" in extend schema mongoose doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have below method in model `UserSchema`:

```
userSchema.virtual('password')
    .set(function(password) {
            this._password = password;
            this.salt = this.makeSalt();
            this.hashed_password = this.encryptPassword(password);
    })
    .get(function() {
            return this._password;
    }
);
```

but when I create new `teacher` I have error `hashed_password is required`. So I think that method `virtual` from `userSchema` isn't inheritance in `teacherSchema`. How can I set that `teacherSchema` inheritances method like `virtual` from `userSchema`?

**model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
extend = require('mongoose-extend-schema');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
        maxLength: 32
    },
    surname: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
        maxLength: 32
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
        lowercase: true
    },
hashed_password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    initials: String
});

userSchema.virtual('password')
    .set(function(password) {
            this._password = password;
            this.salt = this.makeSalt();
            this.hashed_password = this.encryptPassword(password);
    })
    .get(function() {
            return this._password;
    }
);



const studentSchema = extend(userSchema, {
    teachers: []   
});

const teacherSchema = extend(userSchema, {
    isActiveTutor: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
})
  


const User =  mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
const Student = mongoose.model('Student', studentSchema);
const Teacher = mongoose.model('Teacher', teacherSchema);

module.exports = {
    User,
    Student,
    Teacher
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using [mongoose-extend-schema](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-extend-schema) NPM and this only merge objects from source schema to new schema, like this,

```
function extendSchema (Schema, definition, options) {
  return new mongoose.Schema(
    Object.assign({}, Schema.obj, definition),
    options
  );
}
```

---

There is a new method in mongoose called [clone()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/schema.html#schema_Schema-clone), this returns a deep copy of the schema, and a [add()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/schema.html#schema_Schema-add), Adds key path / schema type pairs to this schema and You can also `add()` another schema and copy over all paths, virtuals, getters, setters, indexes, methods, and statics.

I am describing 2 approaches, you can use anyone from both,

#### 1) Clone parent schema and add new properties to it

```
// Skipping your 1) User Schema and 2) Virtual Function, because its remain same

const studentSchema = userSchema.clone();
studentSchema.add({
    teachers: []
});

const teacherSchema = userSchema.clone();
teacherSchema.add({
    isActiveTutor: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
const Student = mongoose.model('Student', studentSchema);
const Teacher = mongoose.model('Teacher', teacherSchema);

module.exports = { User, Student, Teacher }
```

#### 2) Create new schema and add parent schema to it

```
// Skipping your 1) User Schema and 2) Virtual Function, because its remain same

const studentSchema = new Schema({
    teachers: []
}).add(userSchema);

const teacherSchema = new Schema({
    isActiveTutor: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
}).add(userSchema);

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
const Student = mongoose.model('Student', studentSchema);
const Teacher = mongoose.model('Teacher', teacherSchema);

module.exports = { User, Student, Teacher }
```